# Anonymous Type and Null

Tags: c#, xml, linq, anonymous-types

Our company utilizes a service, which gives developers access to their application through a *Rest Api*.  So based on the content that this application generates, I built a data model to represent the *Extensible Markup Language (XML)* for easier modification.

However the API generates two separate areas for data:

```
var responses = submission.Sections.SelectMany(obj =>
     obj.Screens.Screen.Responses.Response.Select(response => 
     new { response.Label, response.Value, response.Type })).ToList();
```

---

```
var responses = submission.Sections.SelectMany(obj =>
     obj.Screens.Screen.Responses.Responses.Response.Select(response => 
     new { response.Label, response.Value, response.Type })).ToList();
```

As you can see when I'm building the content `Responses.Response` is where a bulk of the data, however sometimes it utilizes `Responses.Responses.Response`.  Is there a way to do a preliminary projection on the data?  This way I could test for the `null` that is occasionally thrown in `Responses.Response`?

That way I could do something along these lines:

```
if(obj != null)
{
     // Responses.Response
}
else
{
     //Responses.Responses.Response
}
```

Is that even possible with Linq?  The problem is because `response.Value` is `null` in certain instances, it throws a `Null Argument Exception`.

Comment: If you down vote, you should express what is wrong with the question.

Comment: Are you asking if you can chain `Select`s? Like `q.Select(r=>r.Response).Select(r => r.InnerResponse).Select(r => r.EvenDeeper)...`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Not quote, the code I have correlates the model correctly.  However, how could I check for a `null` in `Responses.Response` so that it knows that it should go to `Responses.Responses.Response`.

Comment: You could "wait" for the ?. feature that .NET will have soon... other than that i'm not sure :(

Comment: Stuff like `obj.Screens.Screen.Responses.Responses.Response.` looks ugly. Why so many identical or nearly identical names?

Comment: Try to come up with the way you want code to look like (you already have normal "?:" and "??" answers but no comments there if you ok with either of answers). Maybe `...Response.OrDefault().Response.OrDefault().Select...`? (where `OrDefault` would return some sort of matching [null object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) )

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Well, that is what the third party names their data in the API.  So when Visual Studio builds the model it just uses the Xml Element name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the null-coalescing operator:

```
var responses = submission.Sections.SelectMany(obj =>
 (obj.Screens.Screen.Responses.Response ?? obj.Screen.Responses.Responses.Response).Select(response => 
 new { response.Label, response.Value, response.Type })).ToList();
```